# Objective-C powf() equivalent function in Java

Tags: java, objective-c, function

Is there a function Java equivalent to Objective-C `float powf(float, float)`?

Thank you.

Comment: It is `Math.pow`. You can find with a google for `java pow`.

Comment: This works for `double` and `float` types. I suggest you only use `double` unless you have *very good* reason to use `float`. BTW: You would be surprised how many answers google can give re: java+whatever or java+tutorial+whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two options

```
double d = Math.pow(a, b);
```

or add to the start of the java file

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
```

and use

```
double d = pow(a, b);
```

BTW Your IDE can usually do this refactoring.

Comment: Thank you. Might be simple question but to tell the truth I was searching wrong  I guess in Google.

Comment: It might be worth a quick read over this class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: Yes, definitely. Thank you.